# how to get a member from derived class through the base class except using pure virtual

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived, pure-virtual

I've class G.

---

class B : public G

class A : public B

---

class D : public G

class C : public D

---

class F : public G

class E : public F

---

From a different class, I've an access to G (G sorry!!). I've to get some memeber of class A (for example, string m_Astr).

How can I access the A string? If I use pure virtual in class G, I'll have to implement this getStr function in E and C in addition to the implementation of A, and I need it for A only.

please help

Comment: What does your `E` object have to do with any `A`?

Comment: I take it you mean, you want to access `A` via a reference to `B` or `G` (base classes of `A`), not `E` (an unrelated class, which can't be an instance of `A`)? In the first case, `dynamic_cast` is probably what you want; in the second, you can't, since there's no `A` to access.

Comment: A is neither an ancestor nor a descendent of E.

Comment: sorry! I meant G, not E.. editted :(

Comment: Yes Mike, G, (not E). can you please explain me more how to use the dynamic cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **know** (somehow) that the object pointed to is *actually* an instance of an `A`, then you can use `static_cast`:

```
G* p = get_the_thing();
A* a = static_cast <A*> (p); // OK
```

However, if the object pointed to by `p` above doesn't instantiate an `A`, then the above code will yield undefined behavior.

A more safe approach would be to use `dynamic_cast`,

```
G* p = get_the_thing();
A* a = dynamic_cast <A*> (p); // OK
```

Here, `a` will be `NULL` if `p` isn't *actually* an `A`.  However, `dynamic_cast` can only be used in this manner with polymorphic classes:  the base class must have at least one `virtual` function.  A `virtual` destructor would do nicely here.